# MeteorJS: MongoDB, sort and filter

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So, this should be straightforward for anyone using meteor and mongodb...

Essentially, I want to filter my `.find()` and `sort` it:

Here is what I have:

```
.find({_id: {$ne: postID}, sort: {createdAt: -1}).fetch(); // doesn't work, returns nothing..
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly brace is missing after the query criteria so you're effectively passing a single param instead of 2.

```
.find({_id: {$ne: postID}}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch();
```